# insert additional WHERE condition into a .sql file using R

Tags: r, string, insert

I have a .sql file that I use with SQL Server Management Studio. I use the same file within my R script to pull the data directly into R (as below) and this works well.

```
query <- paste(readLines("SQL_FILE.sql"), collapse="\n") # read sql query from hard drive
con <- odbcConnect(dsn ="DATABASE_NAME") # connect to database
dt <- sqlQuery(con, query, rows_at_time = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

What I need is to insert an additional condition of which the values are being genarated in R environment, to the beginning of the *WHERE* clause in the .sql file using R. I solved this with below approach:

```
queryStart <- "SELECT * FROM ANALYSIS_VIEW A WHERE 1=1 AND A.COLUMN_X IN("
filteringValuesForX <- c("FILTERING_VALUE_X1", "FILTERING_VALUE_X2")
queryEnd <- ") AND A.COLUMN_Y = 'FILTERING_VALUE_Y1';"

query <-
  paste0(queryStart,
         toString(paste("'",filteringValuesForX ,"'", sep='')),
         queryEnd)
query
```

And the output is:

```
"SELECT * FROM ANALYSIS_VIEW A WHERE 1=1 AND A.COLUMN_X IN('FILTERING_VALUE_X1', 'FILTERING_VALUE_X2') AND A.COLUMN_Y = 'FILTERING_VALUE_Y1';"
```

However, I am looking for a better solution because of below reasons:

1. It is not dynamic; when I update the .sql file using SQL Server Management Studio, I need to update *queryStart* and *queryEnd* variables manually as well.
2. The actual SQL script is very long, and I don't want to see all the SQL code in the R script.

Note: There are other *WHERE* clauses in the original .sql file. However, I want this update only for one specific *WHERE* clause. To point out this specific one, I added the statement "1=1".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot paste this condition at the end of the query? (I mean, instead of inserting it in the middle of it.) It would be simpler.

Comment: It is because I need this insertion in one of the sub-queries, not at the end of the whole query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way! 
But before accepting my solution as an answer, I will wait for one more day to see if there is a better answer. So, please, feel free to suggest other approaches.

```
replaceWithThis <- paste(" A.COLUMN_X IN(", toString(paste("'",filteringValuesForX ,"'", sep='')), ")", " ", collapse = "\n")
query <- sub(x = query, pattern = "1=1 AND A.COLUMN_X IN('FILTERING_VALUE_X1', 'FILTERING_VALUE_X2') ", replacement = replaceWithThis)
query
```

For this example, to avoid the duplicete *WHERE*  condition, I've used the `pattern = "1=1 AND A.COLUMN_X IN('FILTERING_VALUE_X1', 'FILTERING_VALUE_X2') "` . In original data it is enough to replace `1=1`.

The output is:

```
"SELECT * FROM ANALYSIS_VIEW A WHERE 1=1 AND A.COLUMN_X IN('FILTERING_VALUE_X1', 'FILTERING_VALUE_X2') AND A.COLUMN_Y = 'FILTERING_VALUE_Y1';"
```